# How to uninstall specific version of app when we installed two different version of same application in ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

I have installed two different versions of dbeaver on Ubuntu.

- 22.2.1
- 22.2.2

And I can open both at a same time.

Can someone please help me to uninstall 1 of them?

Comment: how did you install dbeaver?

Comment: The exact command you used to install each one would be necessary to help you remove one. What Ubuntu product and version are you using. You have tagged 3 different.

Comment: @Niklas I have installed using .deb file just opened with software Install Application

Comment: @David - I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: @Nishant do you still have the deb file? I think when you reopen the deb file with the software install application you can remove it by clicking the trash icon.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange how you installed two versions of that application, because it is only available in a single version as a snap install. We can tell you how to remove the snap version, but not how to remove the other version you installed, because that depends on the way you installed it, and only you can know that.

A snap version is removed with the Software Center, or with the command

```
sudo snap remove dbeaver-ce
```

If you installed the other package using a `.deb` installation file, you will also to remove that version using the Software Center. If you installed it a different way, then it depends on how you installed it.